# How to integrate $\int\frac{\ln^5 x}xdx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

Can someone explain,why i can`t integrate this?
$$\int\frac{\ln^5 x}xdx=\int\ln^5 x\ d(\ln x)$$

I`m really sorry for stupid question.

Comment: There are no stupid questions, just badly written ones.

Comment: @inbfor Would it be easier for you if it were written $\int y^5 dy$, where $y=\ln(x)$?

Comment: can you show what have you done and where is your truble?

Comment: You almost wrote the solution in the question.

Comment: Why you think you cant integrate this? Just go on, you already did it. Think of $\ln(x)=t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that 
$$
\int f'(x)(f(x))^ndx=\frac1{n+1} (f(x))^{n+1}+C,\quad n \neq-1,
$$ then rewrite your integral as
$$
\int\frac{\ln^5 x}xdx=\int(\ln x)'(\ln x)^5\: dx.
$$ Hoping you can take it from here.